# If statement inside preg_replace?

Tags: php, regex

I'm using this code currently, to convert a BBCode Quote tag to HTML. As you probably know, a quote source isn't necessary to make a quote on most forums. And I'd like to print just "Quote" when there's no quote source specified.

```
$string = preg_replace("/\[quote(|=(.*?))\]/is","<fieldset style=\"border:1px dashed #999999;\"><legend>$2</legend>",$string);
```

It seems like I can't use an if statement with the $2 reference. So what's my alternative? (Or am I just doing something wrong... ?)

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look [preg_replace_callback](http://php.net/manual/de/function.preg-replace-callback.php). You can pass a callback that gets called for every match. In this callback you will be able to modify the matches and set the default to "Quote".